# Android: How can I put an image on top of google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an android app in which I want to put an image at the bottom right corner of the google map. when user clicks on that image it will move the camera to the current location of the camera was zoomed or moved to a different location.  What is the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use frame layout or you can use Relative layout also.

Comment: Can you please explain with code as google maps is hiding the image behind it when done in that way.

Comment: @Kanika post your current code. Using a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Z-Index matters Kanika. Make sure whatever you want to be on "bottom" is at the top of your layout file.

i.e.

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <GoogleMap>

    <ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

if you do the other way around, googleMap will be overtop of imageView.

Comment: I know and I did it in the same way and the image did not show up. And yes the imageview had an image defined in it.

Comment: I have personally done this. So I'm positive you can accomplish this very easily. What is your parent of the map layout and image layout? Can you please share your XML. I will fix it for you no problem.